# Position sticky not working with columns headers

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I want to use the position sticky, but I noticed that if the content has the style columns, it doesnt work. This is a example i made in JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3f056yqv/

```
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF000;
}

.min {
  width: 48%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.notworking {
  columns: 100px 3;
}
```

```
<div class="min">
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Working 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Working 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Working 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="min notworking">
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Not Working 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Not Working 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Not Working 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a fix for this? Or maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky will not work in column logic. Because the elements in the column are not in a fixed position. For example, they floats in the 1. 2. or 3. column. You can use `grid` instead of columns.

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF000;
}

.min {
  width: 48%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.notworking {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="min">
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Working 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Working 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Working 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="min notworking">
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Not Working 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Not Working 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky">Not Working 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```